# Десериализаровать в List

Tags: c#, json, list

Как десериализировать данный ответ:

`{
  "response":
  [
 218803928,317010917,179681066,173431607,356408021,421702993,295920106,121375474,261654407,322744642,307578021,384790605,223522189,141711244,286562711,204691290,343742090,474494798,237102289,478504542,177436279,196611542,66950243,189052497,331084770,421534614,225194958,224984110,204442992,48511162,436569015,253920936,460621648
  ]
}`

Comment: Десериализуйте как `List<int>`.

Comment: @AresGod пытался, null